# How to merge two array of objects when there is edit flag

Tags: javascript, arrays, collections, lodash

I am having the array of objects like below

Array 1:

```
[{id: 1, name: 'Golden', isEdited: true}, {id: 2, name: 'Pearl'}]
```

Array 2:

```
[{id: 1, name: 'Golden'}, {id: 2, name: 'Pearlblue'}, , {id: 3, name: 'Orange'}]
```

Now i would like to merge the two arrays if the object contains isEdited flag means then that object should not be updated.

Expected result should be

```
[{id: 1, name: 'Golden', isEdited: true}, {id: 2, name: 'Pearlblue'}, {id: 3, name: 'Orange'}]
```

I have tried with the below approach

```
b.map((battr) => {
 return {
   ...a[battr.id],
   ...battr
 }
})
```

But it returns the output as

```
[{id: 1, name: 'Golden'}, {id: 2, name: 'Pearlblue'}, {id: 3, name: 'Orange'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull, your `id`s don't match your array indexes.
Hence in your attempt `a[battr.id]` should be replaced by something like `a.find(a => a.id === battr.id)`

Your example is confusing since in both arrays the name is 'Golden' for id=1, but assuming you want only the properties from array A if isEdited=true, your solution could be :

```
b.map((b_attr) => {
  var matchingA = a.find(a_attr => a_attr.id === b_attr.id);
  if (matchingA && matchingA.isEdited)
    return matchingA;
  else
    return { ...matchingA, ...b_attr }
})
```

Comment: If there is a case where a has objects like `[{id: 1, name: 'Golden', isEdited: true}, {id: 2, name: 'Pearl'}, {id: 4, name: 'Red'}]`
and if we run the above logic then at that time the `{id: 4, name: 'Red'}` is missed out.

Comment: then add thoses objects after the above logic :
`b.map( ... ).concat(a.filter(x => !b.some(y => y.id === x.id)))`